# Docker images are not built from the latest code

Tags: docker, github-actions

I build a docker image in GitHub Actions workflow:

```yaml
- name: Build and push frontend
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
  with:
    no-cache: true
    context: frontend/
    file: frontend/Dockerfile.development
    push: true
    tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}/${{ secrets.FRONTEND_DEV }}:latest
```

And I push it to the docker hub.

The problem is that when I make any changes, and push them to GitHub they appear on GitHub, but the image does not have these changes.

Another thing is that it used to work as intended, but a couple of days ago changes stopped being present in the newly built docker image.

I tried to add another step to clean up the docker cache:

```yaml
- name: Clean Docker cache
  run: |
    docker system prune -a
    docker system prune --all --force
    docker volume prune --force
    docker network prune --force
```

But the problem is still present.

Comment: What do you set as trigger for the action?